# Defining constant/ro properties on objects with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, tsc

Using TypeScript, is there any way to enforce non-reassignment?

Say I have this:

```
fn.foo = 5;
fn.foo = 6;
```

is there a way to get a compile error on the second line? As soon as I assign the foo property, it should be `ReadOnly` I suppose.

My case foo could adhere to this interface:

```
export interface RO {
  [readonly key: string]: any
}
```

but I am not sure if that syntax works out.

Comment: What is the type of `fn` ?

Comment: fn could be any object, over which I have control of the source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a class you can mark the field itself as `readonly` and you can only assign it in the constructor:

```
class Test {
    readonly foo : string;
    constructor () {
        this.foo = "";
    }
}

let fn = new Test();
fn.foo = "" // Error
```

If you are using object literals you can use an explicit type to not allow mutation of a field just it's initial assignment:

```
let fn : {
    readonly foo: string
} = {
    foo: "1"
}
```

You could also use `Object.freeze` which has runtime behavior as well:

```
let fn  = Object.freeze({
    foo: "1"
})
fn.foo = "" // error
```

In either case you can create a `readonly` field that is only assignable on object creation. There is no way to create a field that is only assignable once after initialization such as in your example.

**Edit**

Note that `readonly` is not very strong,it does nto cause type incompatibility between two types with the same fields:

```
let fn  = Object.freeze({
    foo: "1"
}) // foo is readonly 
let nonReadonlyFn : { foo: string } =fn; // foo is not readonly but assignment is allowed
nonReadonlyFn.foo = "" // not a compiler error.
```

**Update**

If you don't know the keys you can create a readonly index signature:

```
let fn: { 
    readonly [n: string] : string
} = { foo: "" };
fn["foo"] ="" // error
console.log(fn["foo"])
```

A common way to create readonly objects without initializing them all at once is to have a mutable version, mutate it and when you are done assigning it to a readonly version:

```
let fnNotReadOnly: { 
    [n: string] : string
} ;
fnNotReadOnly["foo"] = "";
//When done mutating:
let fn : { 
    readonly [n: string] : string
} =  fnNotReadOnly;

fn["foo"] = ""
console.log(fn["foo"])
```

Comment: thanks, that's what I was thinking. What if the properties are added dynamically though? Anything that can be done in that case?

Comment: Only if you assign it to some other variable after you finish creating it (with that variable having `readonly` fields )

Comment: readonly index signature perhaps? Where all props are readonly? that would work for my use case. I updated the OP to show what I meant.

Comment: I that will still not allow assignment, justreadonly access that might be what you are looking for if you don't know the keys

Comment: Sorry I did not follow what you said 100%

Comment: Yeah .. that sentence got way from me. I updated the answer with what I meant :)

Comment: ok I think I see it now, I filed this ticket with TS on Github, let me know what you think: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25753

Comment: Don't think you will have much luck with that. It's hard to track the first assignment of the field especially when there is control flow involved. The assigning it on creation is still the best way, or have a mutable version and then assign it to the readonly version (added a code sample to the answer)

Comment: Yeah in this case I'd want to support unknown properties being added after declaration.